# A question about Fourier transform and norm

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and we can obtain that $\mathcal{F}(f) \in \mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R}^d) $, which is the Fourier transform of $f$. Since we have the conclusion that $f$ and $\mathcal{F}(f) $ have the same $L_2$ norm. And my question is that how about their $L_1$ norm？

Comment: There is no such relation concerning the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: @amsmath I think that “no such relation” maybe hard to say, I mean that if I give any relation about the $L^1$ norm, there exists a counterexample of the relation……

Comment: @user510742 I think what amsmath means is there is no known result connecting $L^{1}$ norms of a function and its Fourier transform. One precise result is: $f\to \hat {f}$ is not a bounded w.r.t. $L^{1}$ norm on $\mathbb S (\mathbb  R^{d})$

Comment: @user510742 Vague questions result in vague answers.

Comment: Maybe the question could be formalized in the following way: if we consider $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as a normed space with the $L^1$ norm, is the Fourier transform on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ a bounded operator? Is its inverse bounded?

Comment: @amsmath hhhh since I didn’t see any conclusion about them

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy OK, thanks！

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa Yes, you’re right.

Comment: @user510742 You see? The question posed by Lorenzo is concrete. Yours is posed in vague terms. Next time, before you ask a question, you should think about how to ask it properly. It's not good if people here have to state the question for you.

Comment: @amsmath Alright (^ ^)